# Hibernate row mappers

Tags: hibernate, hql

I got my LogEventType in my object array. Is there a way of creating a new LogEventType using its constructor? This is possible i LogEventType was a mapped entity but it is not. Created table logeventtype using sql and regular inserts. In this case returning

```
new LogEventType(obj[0],obj[1]);
```

would be fine but i will need to fetch a list later.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
String queryString = "select type.eventid, type.value from logeventtype type where type.eventid = :eventid";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(queryString).setParameter("eventid", enventId);
Object[] obj = (Object[]) query.uniqueResult();
```

Edit:
This is what I have been trying

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
String queryString = "select new com.company.Test(type.value) from logeventtype type where type.eventid = :eventid";
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString).setParameter("eventid", 1l);
Object[] obj = (Object[]) query.uniqueResult();
```

I get logeventtype is not mapped.

Comment: I read the question 3 times, and honestly I still don't get what you are trying to ask...

Comment: Can I get LogEventType directly from my query? LogEventType is not managed by hibernate.

Comment: but you said you created table for LogEventType.  I think it is better if you can make your question clearer so that people understand your problem better.  Btw, you can do `select new SomeClass(x.fieldA, x.fieldB) from SomeX x where x.foo = "balbalbla";` in HQL.  I don't know whether it is relevant to your question though

Comment: Thats what I want but does SomeClass has to be mapped by Hibernate? I can't use hql when my table isn't managed by hibernate?

Comment: No, it does not need to be mapped. Any POJO class with a suitable ctor works fine.  Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html Section 16.6

Comment: regarding your edit: if your logeventtype is not  mapped, how do u expect Hibernate work for you?  Again, after your update, I am even more confused about what your problem is.  Can u reorganize your question to make other easier to understand your problem?

Comment: Se answer. Thats what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do this with

```
    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select * from logeventtype ").addScalar("eventId", StandardBasicTypes.LONG)
            .addScalar("value", StandardBasicTypes.STRING).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(LogEventType.class));
```